# Error: initial term of field expression must be a concrete sobject list

Tags: apex

I hada custom setting with Status value , I need to compare status in response of webservice with custom setting and then add in list to display.

Only those need to be display whose status are in Custom setting, My code below

```
global static List<smb_Contract> getContracts(string customerId) {
        if (string.isBlank(customerId)) return null;

        Bmn_ContactCC cc = new Bmn_ContactCC();
        DMS_1DataManagement_v3.ContractList contracts = cc.getData(customerId); );

        system.debug('==RESULT=='+contracts );
        List<smb_Contract> result = new List<smb_Contract>();

        if (contracts.contract == null) return result;


        for (DMS_1DataManagement_v3.Contract contract : contracts.contract) {
             List<Contract_Status__c> Consta = Contract_Status__c.getall().values();
               for(List<Contract_Status__c> Cn :Consta){
             //if(Cn.Name==contract.contractStatus)
             if(Cn.Name == contract.contractStatus) 
             result.add(new smb_Contract(contract));
             }
             }
               //  if(contract.contractStatus.equalsignorecase('active')||contract.contractStatus.equalsignorecase('sent')){

            //}
       // }   


           result.sort();        
        return result;

     }
```

Comment: probably your `contracts.contract` is not a list.

Comment: Error could be in this line: result.add(new smb_Contract(contract));

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` [loop](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for.htm) structure is incorrect. If your collection variable is of type `List<MySetting__c>`, then your loop variable must be of type `MySetting__c`.

So change:

```
for (List<Contract_Status__c> Cn : Consta)
```

to:

```
for (Contract_Status setting : Contract_Status__c.getAll().values())
```

You don't really need to cache the list, so I would just inline it into the loop. And please for the sake of the programmers who follow you, put a little more effort into using readable names!